# Where does Android 2.3.6 do the certificate hostname verification?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I am looking for the actual implementation of the certificate hostname verification in Android (not interfaces or abstract classes ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Android apps can use either the JRE's or the Apache HttpClient's hostname verification. In the former case, the verification is in X509TrustManagerImpl.java. In the latter case it is in AbstractVerifier.java